# Can slave process be dynamically provisioned based on load using Spring Cloud data flow?

Tags: spring-cloud-dataflow

We are currently using Spring batch - remote chunking for scaling batch process . Thinking of using Cloud data flow but would like to know if based on load Slaves can be dynamically provisioned?
we are deployed in Google Cloud and hence want to think of using Spring Cloud data flow support for kubernetes as well if Cloud data flow would fit our needs ?

Answer (score 1):

When using the batch extensions of Spring Cloud Task (specifically the `DeployerPartitionHandler`), workers are dynamically launched as needed.  That `PartitionHandler` allows you to configure a maxiumum number of workers, then it will process each partition as an independent worker up to that max (processing the rest of the partitions as others finish up).  The "dynamic" aspect is really controlled by the number of partitions returned by the `Partitioner`.  The more partitions returned means the more workers launched.

You can see a simple example configured to use CloudFoundry in this repo: https://github.com/mminella/S3JDBC  The main difference between it and what you'd need is that you'd swap out the `CloudFoundryTaskLauncher` for a `KubernetesTaskLauncher` and it's appropriate configuration.

Comment: Thanks Michael.It helps .Currently we use MessagingPartitionHandler since we are  sending data via messaging middleware ActiveMQ.If that's the case then should we use multiple Partition Handlers- (i.e) one for sending messaging and other for provisioning worker node ?

Comment: No.  The `DeployerPartitionHandler` is responsible for launching the workers as well as providing the metadata.  It uses Boot properties to pass the values that would be sent over ActiveMQ so there is no need for messaging middleware when using this approach.